# What is the difference between GNOME desktop and Ubuntu in SDDM?

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, gdm, sddm

I installed Kubuntu on my machine, and then decided to try the regular GNOME desktop.
Thus I installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and logged in from the welcome screen running SDDM.
This has been a successful attempt on using both sessions, however...

it also resulted in having entries for GNOME and (plain) Ubuntu in SDDM, with some repeated and weirdly sorted:

- GNOME classic
- GNOME on Xorg
- GNOME on Xorg .... (duplicated)
- Plasma
- Ubuntu
- GNOME (Wayland)
- Ubuntu on Wayland (Wayland)
- Plasma (Wayland) (Wayland)

So I have two questions:

1. Is there any difference between `GNOME on Xorg` and `Ubuntu` or `GNOME (Wayland)` and `Ubuntu on Wayland`?
2. How can I organize (remove, rename, and rearrange)* the entries shown here?
   I've actually tried looking for the SDDM documentation, but couldn't follow through because there wasn't an `/etc/sddm.conf` and I don't know much about what's going on here ...
   ¯\_( ツ )_/¯

PS. I'm running Kubutnu 20.10.

Comment: Maybe look at the different files in `/usr/share/xsessions/`.  There should be one file for each DE that it tries to load. Unless SDDM doesn't use that directory.

Comment: Xorg and Wayland are display managers.  They make the petty pictures.  Xorg is old and still works, but bloated.  Wayland is the new and improved(?) display manager.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, and after exploring the folders `/usr/share/{xsessions,wayland-sessions}/` I got a hint of what goes on in there.

I was also able to find the difference between GNOME and Ubuntu sessions... (at a technical level but not visible per se), and how to rename and rearrange the entries in the menu.

To rearrange the entries I preceeded them with a number on how they're to be read.
I also changed the extension from `.desktop` to `.disabled` for those that I didn't want to show.

The resulting entries were these:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions
... 0-plasma.desktop
... 1-ubuntu.desktop
... 2-gnome-classic.desktop
... gnome.disabled -> gnome-xorg.disabled
... gnome-xorg.disabled
```

When showing the corresponding files, I was able to change the desktop-session names for better consistency:

E.g.

```
$ sudo vim /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-xorg.desktop
...
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME on Xorg
Comment=This session logs you into GNOME
...
```

change what comes after `Name` to whatever you need, or in my case `Gnome` (because I prefer title case than all caps).

For the Wayland sessions, I noticed SDDM already adds its own tag: `(Wayland)` so I removed that from the name.

```
GNOME on Xorg -> Gnome   # Since I don't understand Xorg, I'll remove that. 
                         # I also know GNOME has all caps, but I prefer no caps.
Ubuntu on Wayland -> Ubuntu    # Since SDDM already adds (Wayland) by default. 
Plasma (Wayland)  -> Plasma    # Because SDDM added an additional (Wayland).
```

Since finding that `gnome.desktop` (later renamed by me) was pointing to `gnome-xorg.desktop`, this results in a repeated entry in SDDM.

Finally, the difference between them and `ubuntu.desktop` consists of a couple of env variables when running the command `gnome-desktop` via the DM.

I should mention that this is exploratory programming, and therefore people following this must be ready to get their hands dirty with the Display Manager.

Thanks.